# mariaDB 10.1 simple SELECT many seconds large database

Tags: php, mysql, select, mariadb

I do a simple SELECT (tried with and without LIMIT 1)...

```
SELECT * FROM `links_db` WHERE `link` LIKE '__some_url__'  ; // 9.45 sec
SELECT * FROM `links_db` WHERE `link` LIKE '__some_url__' LIMIT 1 ; // 8 sec
SELECT `link` FROM `links_db` WHERE `link` LIKE '__some_url__' ; // 5 sec
SELECT `link` FROM `links_db` WHERE `link` LIKE '__some_url__' LIMIT 1 ; // 5 sec
```

But the problem is that my database is 300 mb... it takes 5 seconds to perform this single and simple task...

I upgraded from MYSQL 5.5 to MariaDB 10.1 but still 5 seconds...

Is there a setting in my.cnf that could help make the SELECT faster ?

Comment: How many rows is your table? Do you have indexes? Use an `=` if you are looking for an exact match. This doesn't seem to be PHP related either..

Comment: Can you provide an actual query?

Comment: the table have 70 000 rows... with = instead of LIKE it's 5 sec instead of 9

Answer (score 0):

I think something was wrong in my.cnf...

I removed ALL lines (to let mariaDB have it's own default values) exept those few :

```
[mysqld]
performance-schema=1
tmpdir=/home/tmp
general_log=0
slow_query_log=0
innodb_file_per_table=1
default-storage-engine=InnoDB
innodb_buffer_pool_size=2000M
```

and the SELECT passed from 9 secs to 140ms ;)

Answer (score 0):

(To much for a Comment.)

300MB for 70K rows?  You have some wide columns?

Is the column `link` indexed?

Let's see `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.

What settings did you remove?  If you had blindly set a lot of things to large value, that could have caused performance problems -- usually by blowing out RAM.

How much RAM do you have?

If you don't have an index on `link`, all of those queries will be performed the same way (see `EXPLAIN`).  The table will scanned, checking each one for the `LIKE`.  If such a row is *early* in the table, then `LIMIT 1` will stop quickly.  (So I assume there was no such.)  With `SELECT *`, all the columns are gathered; this takes more effort.

Do not set `query_cache_size` bigger than 50M.

Comment: What do you mean by "Is link indexes?"

Comment: @JohnR - I means my fingers sometimes fumble.  Is that column indexed?  Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE links_db` so we can see that, and other, details.

Comment: the CREATE is this : CREATE TABLE `links` (
  `link_id` int(255) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `link` text COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`link_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;

Comment: Let's take the question a different direction -- is this a real query in you app?  Or are you asking about the inner workings?  And do you really have a leading wildcard (`_`)?  _That_ is the reason all variants take multiple seconds.